# What is your version control and deployment workflow with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version-control, deployment, workflow

Especially when considering a fresh Rails project, what does your version control and deployment workflow look like? What tools do you use?

I'm interested in answers for Mac, *nix and Windows work machines. Assume a *nix server.

I'll edit for clarity if need be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a copy of my personal Rails 2.1.1 template with preinstalled plugins and frozen gems.
2. Change DB passwords, session secret/name and `deploy.rb`.
3. Create a private or public repository on GitHub as needed.
4. Push the empty rails project to GitHub.
5. SSH to Server and configure apache (copy Virtual Host file and mongrel config files from old project)
6. Create empty database on MySQL server
7. `cap deploy:setup && cap deploy:cold`

If everything works so far: Start developing and committing to GitHub. `cap deploy` as needed.

**Update:** Don't forget to write tests for **everything** you do!

Comment: I think you mean cap deploy:setup

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows Vista and a fresh Ubuntu install at Slicehost.

1. Create a new empty project in
   NetBeans.
2. Fire deprec (http://www.deprec.org) to install
   the Rails stack, including version
   control, on the target slice.
3. Commit the empty project to Subversion.
4. Using Capistrano, test deploy.
5. Begin actual development after I've verified that I can access the
   Rails start page and, possibly,
   scaffolding.  (This is really not
   necessary because I've done this several times and the software works like it says it does.)

Deprec is seriously magic -- it takes the time it takes to clean-start a Rails project (including server configuration and all that jazz) from about a working day down to about an hour -- and that is an hour where you can be doing coding while everything installs.

Answer (score 2):

this guy documents every workflow he's ever experienced

http://subtlegradient.com/articles/2007/03/30/web-development-environment-and-workflow