# Which is a better source control with NetBeans (Ruby on Rails), VSS or Subversion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, netbeans, visual-sourcesafe, netbeans6.8

Which is better source control with NetBeans (Ruby on Rails), VSS or subversion?

I want to use source control, so I want to know which is better for NetBeans (RoR). Visual Source safe or Subversion?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202974/what-is-your-version-control-and-deployment-workflow-with-rails among many others

Comment: Subversion is not a "source safe", it is a version control system. "Source safe" is a product name from Microsoft.

Comment: I still wake up screaming  when I recall the time SourceSafe one morning decided that every file in the repository only had a 50/50 chance to live.  *Don't let this happen to you.*

Comment: for file in `find /path/to/vss/ -type f`; do; [ $[ $RANDOM % 2 ] == 0 ] && rm $file ]; done............. oh wait, n/m... VSS only works in Windows!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely Subversion.

I'd explain why, but Jeff Atwood [has done a great job already](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html) and the blog entry links to other sites with great information.

Avoid VSS like the plague.  You are far better off with SVN or Git.

Answer (score 5):

I can give you the recommendation to use Subversion if possible. Even [according to Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102146111033.aspx), SourceSafe is a rather limited version control system. It lacks quite essential features such as transactional commits/revisions, branching and merge support, an easily corrupted database etc.

Alan de Smet has put up a rather long list here:

> **[Visual SourceSafe: Microsoft's Source Destruction System](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html)**

If you for any reason have to live with VSS make sure that you install all service packs and updates as there are a number of highly critical issues in the RTM version (e.g. [this update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a1a68d8-db11-417c-91ad-02aab484776b&displaylang=en), updates don't come automatically with Windows update).

Answer (score 3):

[Anything but SourceSafe](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html).   In all seriousness though, Java-based IDEs such as Netbeans, Eclipse and IDEA usually have the best support for Subversion.  It's free, and it's fast, and it's solid.

Answer (score 1):

The Subversion Netbeans module is provided as part of the platform and is more likely to be supported than the VSS one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should let an IDE to decide for you which Source ( Control program to use.  If anything, it should be the other way around, but best if the decision to choose each (IDE and source control) are decided by its own merits.  In case the chosen IDE does not have tight integration with the source control, it's not the end of the world or a show stopper.  In other words, you can still be very productive if they're not integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using any source control within Netbeans.

You need to be very cautious about ensuring that you stick to a version of Subversion that your version of Netbeans supports.  Assuming you are using windows you will probably also install tortoise and it constantly checks for tortoise & SVN updates which you may foolishly opt to do and then suddenly your netbeans subversion integration is screwed up.

If you search for netbeans subversion plugin a lot of the top entries include the words "upgrade" and "broke".

My advice would be to avoid the IDE integration altogether.  You reduce the number of things that can break and interfere with your work.  If you learn the command line options you become platform/ide independent.

I gave up on SVN in Netbeans a while ago after getting frustrated with the constant fiddling with the plugin, netbean versions, and svn versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used subversion with Netbeans before and it is very effective - subversion allows you to keep your source organised in a nice, simple folder structure whilst being almost universally supported. Besides all of the VSS haters out there, SVN is almost certainly the best "traditional" versioning system out there.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2019:

- the [Subversion support page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversion1_7) date from 2013, for SVN 1.8
- And the request for SVN 1.9 ([opened in 2015](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256405)) is still pending.

So using the [Git Netbeans integration](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html) is a good choice.

As an aside, Ruby itself just got migrated from Subversion to Git.
The [initial request for that migration was opened three years ago](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11741), and at the time rejected.

But [bugs.ruby-lang.org issue 14632](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14632) opened one year ago (March 2018) went through.

As announced in "**[Ruby Repository Moved to Git from Subversion](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/04/23/move-to-git-from-svn/)**" (April, 23rd 2019),

> Today, the canonical repository of the Ruby programming language was moved to Git from Subversion.
>
> The web interface for the new repository is https://git.ruby-lang.org, and is provided by **[cgit](https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/)**.
> We can keep the commit hash from the contributor on the Ruby repository directly.